# Время высокой точности

Tags: python, время, datetime

Мне нужно , чтобы скрипт запускался в определенное время с точностью до миллисекунд. Например в: 12:30:15.05000
Я просто получал datetime.now и форматировал его до ч:м:с:МС , и постоянно сравнивал его с каким-то временем которое перевел в такой же формат , но оно как будто просто не реагирует.
 простите , что без кода ((

Comment: Это возможно только на операционных системах жёсткого реального времени, и уж точно не на питоне. На "обычном" компьютере обеспечить точность до миллисекунд невозможно.

Comment: ! Жаль , конечно . Но спасибо за это !

Answer (score 0):

Есть 2 варианта:

1. Используйте модуль `datetime`:

   ```
   import datetime
   now = datetime.datetime.now()
   ```
2. Используйте сторонний сервис. Т.е. отправкой запроса на сайт получайте текущую дату и время.

Comment: а есть смысл парсить https://timesrv.ru/ на милисекунды, если есть пинг и будет всегда погрешность ? 2й пункт сомнительный

Comment: 1. В многозадачной системе вызов datetime.now() всегда может быть прерван системой, что даст погрешность; 2. Запрос к стороннему сервису вообще даст запредельную погрешность вплоть до сотен миллисекунд (даже специальные протоколы вроде NTP обеспечивают погрешность лишь до десятков миллисекунд при работе в «домашних» условиях)